# Equalize the value of two lists and return one list in Python?

Tags: python, list

```py
listA = []
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [9, 8, 7]
```

I want to have the below list:

```
listA = [(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7)]
```

Comment: This way, you didn't actually "equalize" the two lists but "zipped" them. You can also say that you want to iterate over two lists in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using `list` and `zip`

```
a = [1, 2, 3] 
b = [9, 8, 7]

print(list(zip(a, b)))

# output 
[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3] 
b = [9, 8, 7]
c= []
for i in range(a):
    int_no=(a[i],b[i])
    c.append(int_no)
print(c)
#output=[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7)]
```